# How do I change the direction of my fire?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm trying to make a fireball that's about to land on an island, but I can't seem to be able to change the direction of the fireball. I'm using a sphere, and I'm using version 2.79. Can you help me out? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wind. Add it by pressing <kbd>SHift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Force Field > Wind*

Just place it at whichever direction you want fire to flow then simply increase strength of wind and you are done.